# What's the proper chaining for WHERE

Tags: mysql, jdatabase

This statement works:

```
$query = "
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM " . $this->s_createtableName . " 
WHERE tm BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW())) 
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
```

In trying to chain the query, this code fails on the `WHERE` statement.

```
$query->select('COUNT(*)');

$query->from('. $this->s_createtableName .');

$query->where("tm BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW())) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY)");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using quote the table name.

You can try this. I guess you missed removing the dots in the from clause. If this does not work, please add the error message you get.

```
$query->select('COUNT(*)');

$query->from($this->s_createtableName);

$query->where("tm BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW())) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY)");
```